# Picture for feed post never shows up on wall

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, feed

I'm using the [facepy python SDK](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) to post topics created in my facebook app to the wall of the user that created the topic (topics are like posts in my app). While posting to the users wall works like a charm it seems impossible to get the image that belongs to that post to show up. It seems like i have tried every combination of values for the POST; just a message and picture, full message + picture + link, etc. But nothing works.

I have ended up with this format which shows each field fine, except the image.

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
-F 'message=I posted a new topic' \
-F 'link=https://www.example.com/topic/123' \
-F 'picture=https://www.example.com/static/topic-123-thumbnail.jpg' \
-F 'name=I\'m running out of topics to test with' \
-F 'caption=Can you predict it?' \
-F 'description=Gotta get some more inspiration' \
https://graph.facebook.com/.../feed
```

This by itself should be enough according to the docs but it does not work, the target URL even has the same image linked through a meta og:image field just to be sure but that does not help either.

I'm having the same problem on another app so this does not seem to be related to this specific facebook app...

Comment: for the actual facepy/python code check here: https://github.com/jgorset/facepy/issues/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right so after almost giving up i found the answer to my woes; Facebook does not accept images from HTTPS URLs. Which is a bit silly i think but there you go.

This was reported as a bug and has been confirmed so hopefully this gets fixed soon; https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292265640815869?browse=search_4ee9d0a062c6a3744310596

In the meantime only serve your images from plain HTTP.